# How to test a link's text in Wicket

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, wicket, wicket-tester

I'm trying to implement a link with dynamic text in Wicket, with the username as its text. My first thought was to do something like this in the markup:

```
<a wicket:id="somelink"><wicket:message key="some.key">bla bla</wicket:message></a>
```

With the properties file looking like this:

```
some.key=Username is: {0}
```

And the code:

```
String username = ...
add(new Link("somelink", new StringResourceModel("some.key", this, null, username)) {
    ...
});
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to test that the link's text is being set to the username (in the unit test that is).
I've tried:

- Using `WicketTester`'s `assertLabel` method, but it can't cast the `Link` to a `Label`
- Using the `Link`'s `getModelObject()` method returns the original message (i.e. before formatting the username into it)
- Adding an id to the message and accessing it directly through a path, doesn't work since I get the message that this path doesn't exist (can you even give an ID to a `wicket:message` element ?)

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

`WicketTester.getTagById(java.lang.String)` or `WicketTester.getTagByWicketId(java.lang.String)`? These return a `TagTester` Object and `TagTester.getValue()` returns the value for this tag. This includes all data between the open tag and the close tag as a String. Then you can use assertEquals on the resulting String and your expectation...

```
TagTester link = WicketTester.getTagByWicketId("someLink");
assertNotNull(link);
String linkText = link.getValue();
asserEquals("Username is: " + username, linkText);
```

Comment: Looks good to me :-) I'll give it a try later on today. Thanks !